# Centripetal force and relation with a fluid surface

Tags: forces

I was reading about the relation between fluid surfaces and effective gravity. The gravity should be perpendicular to the surface of the fluid. When a fluid such as water is in a box that is spinning around the centripetal acceleration is point inward,but the fluid pushes against the back of the box which implies that the effective force is pushing back wards against the box instead of towards the center. How come this result occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's a bigger picture here.

To prepare the ground, let me first discuss two examples of linear acceleration:

You are standing on a scateboard, you are next to a table that is bolted to the floor, and you use your hands to push against that table. Obviously, the outcome will be that *you* start moving, not the table. You are on wheels, the table is rigidly connected to the ground.

The other example:
You are standing on the ground, and you push against a table on wheels. Now it's that table that starts moving.

In the second example your feet have grip on the ground, so in effect the *weight* behind you is not just you, you have all of the weight of the Earth.

The two examples above have in common that the force exerted is *mutual*; you exert a force upon the table, the table exerts a force upon you. Whether or not you are set in motion depends on *how much weight is behind you*.

Now to how this applies in the case of that rotating fluid:
Let's say the fluid is in a circular dish with a vertical rim. Well: *the rim cannot budge*. For that rim to budge it would have to tear apart; the structural integrity of the rim makes it unyielding.

On the the other hand, the fluid in the dish gets readily pushed around; it has *only its own weight* behind it.

Answer (score 0):

The moving water would go in a straight line if no other force acted upon it. This would make it tend to move away from the center of the box. But the walls of the box provide the centripetal force pushing inward against the otherwise straight path of the water, forcing it to move in a curve. So the moving water pushes outward against the walls of the box, and the centripetal force of the walls push inwards against the water.